# How to access report data from Sonarcloud.io aka SonarQube API, or functionality no more available?

Tags: analysis, sonarqube

Thanks to SonarCloud.io, you can perform static code analysis without own infrastructure.

But, is there an API to access data shown in Sonar [dashboard](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=fiware.authzforce.server)?

What I can find so far, is the "[Sonar Web API](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Web+API)" documentation but it looks very scarce. There are also docs for older version, but API documented there seems to be no more available.

Is there more "hidden" API functionality? I can't see it mentioned in the Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1):

Ok no so obvious but at least one possible way is:

- Note the component ID in the TravisCI report
- Use the ID and [this documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions) to get data:

  https://sonarcloud.io/api/measures/component?componentId=&metricKeys=code_smells